# How to select in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Today I build a website for a school with express.
This is a part of my template:

```
center
b
 u Students
br
br
table
    thead
        tr: th First Name
            th Last Name
            th Classroom Name
            th Actions
    tbody
        each item, i in stud
                tr: td #{item.FName}
                    td #{item.LName}
                    td
                    each object, j in classr
                        td option(value='#{object.ID}', selected='#{item.class_id}' == '#{object.ID}') #{object.Name}
                    td
                        a(href='/students/edit?id=#{item.ID}') Edit
                    td
                        a(href='/students/delete?id=#{item.ID}') delete
```

As you can see the third 'td' is false, I just want to display the classroom name (in the classroom database table) link with the classroom id in the students table. How can I do that ?

Thank's for your help (and be gentle with me, my English is approximative, I'm French ^^')

Comment: Do you mean that the third `td` is empty? Is that where you want to display the classroom name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was just an if ^^

I found it by myself in the Jade documentation

```
center
b
 u Students
br
br
table
    thead
        tr: th First Name
            th Last Name
            th Classroom name
            th Actions
    tbody
        each item, i in stud
                tr: td #{item.Nom}
                    td #{item.Prenom}
                    td
                        each object, j in classr
                            if item.class_id == object.ID
                                p #{object.Nom}
                    td
                        a(href='/students/edit?id=#{item.ID}') Editer
                    td
                        a(href='/students/delete?id=#{item.ID}') Supprimer
```

Answer (score 0):

In your third td, a **select** tag is missing. Then in your iteration (below the each statement), you don't need to specify a td before the **option** tag.

```
tbody
    each item, i in stud
            tr: td #{item.FName}
                td #{item.LName}
                td
                    select(name='classRoom')
                        each object, j in classr
                            option(value='#{object.ID}', selected='#{item.class_id}' == '#{object.ID}') #{object.Name}
                td
                    a(href='/students/edit?id=#{item.ID}') Edit
                td
                    a(href='/students/delete?id=#{item.ID}') delete
```